# R Colored dendrogram suggestions?

Tags: r

I want to make colored dendrograms and have yet to find a sufficient library: http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=79
This graphic/library looks promising but cannot install the A2E library?
Trying to install on windows, downloaded the `tar.gz` file and cannot install package from the R console.

In addition:

```
Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In gzfile(file, "r") :
  cannot open compressed file 'A2R_0.0-4.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Can anyone see if they can get this A2R library working, confirm error, or suggest a good colored dendrogram library?

Comment: Here's a post on coloring dendrograms from a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720307/change-dendrogram-leafs-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It might help if you spelled it correctly.) `A2R` is a source package. So you might need to have the system toolchain for compilation. Those are typically in your system if you are on Linux, but not if you are on a Mac (as I am) or on Windows. The package does compile from source on a Mac. And the compilation process may not have needed the toolchain. So try this:

```
install.packages("<fullpath> A2R_0.0-4.tar.gz", type ="source")
```

There are a few other dependencies: 'trimcluster', 'prabclus' , 'MASS' , 'cluster', 'mclust', 'flexmix', 'modeltools', 'stats4',  'multcomp', 'mvtnorm'. I am able to get most of that graphic but the left side curve does not appear as shown and I did get an error:

```
     Error in hubertgamma[i] <- cluster.stats(d.usa, cutree(h.usa, k = i +  : 
  replacement has length zero:
```

[image: This is the example plot]

If you do not want the heights of the dendrogram scaled to their depth you can add this modification to the hclust object:

```
h.usa$height <- log(h.usa$height)
```

Comment: thx yes i needed the type="source" > install.packages("C:/Revolution/R-Enterprise-4.3/A2R_0.0-4.tar.gz", type ="source")
inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name

Comment: you mentioned you've used this before, i have it now working, but am trying to figure out how to alter lengths or depths of branches, as i have a larger dataset and am finding the last layer of the dendrogram branches to have almost 0 height.  I figured out how to add more colors etc already.  Any tips appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question.

Comment: After looking at the code and examining the hclust object I wondered if `log()-ing` the heights would work and it did. Code above and then just rerun the A2Rplot() call.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dendrapply()` function in R's built-in dendrogram code to apply custom leaf and node coloring. See the [following mailing list thread](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/06/12/7578.html) for hints.